# How to install CPLEX optimization studio, or just contact IBM?

Tags: download, mathematical-optimization, cplex

I have tried every link possible to download CPLEX optimization studio, and they are all dead or lead to errors or unrelated matters. I remember having great difficulty before to download and install it on my old laptop, but now it just seems impossible... What's more, all customer service and IBM contact forms and links/emails seem dead as well, is this company gone under or something??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The free CPLEX edition is available at [here](https://www.ibm.com/account/reg/us-en/signup?formid=urx-20028)

What is [free](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/what-free-ibm-cplex-alex-fleischer/) with CPLEX ?

And [IBM support](https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/?language=en_US)